# Inject request scoped bean into another bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I want to create a UUID that is unique in a request life cycle.
To do this, I create a UUID bean with the @Scope("request") annotation.

```
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public UUID requestUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

I want to access this bean in my controller. So I inject it with @Autowired.
This works fine.

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    UUID uuid;

    @Autowired
    WelcomeMessageService welcomeMessageService;

    @Autowired
    IssueNotificationService issueNotificationService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println(uuid);
        PortalUserDetails userLog = getPortalUserDetails();

        BusinessObjectCollection<WelcomeMessage> welcomeMessages = welcomeMessageService.findWelcomeMessages(
                20,
                0,
                userLog.getZenithUser(),
                userLog.getConnectionGroup().getConnectionGroupCode(),
                "FR");
        if(welcomeMessages!=null) {
            model.addAttribute("welcomeMessages", welcomeMessages.getItems());
        }

        BusinessObjectCollection<IssueNotification> issueNotifications =
                issueNotificationService.findIssueNotifications(userLog.getZenithUser());

        if(welcomeMessages!=null) {
            model.addAttribute("welcomeMessages", welcomeMessages.getItems());
        }
        model.addAttribute("issueNotifications", issueNotifications);

        return "index";
    }
}
```

The controller call multiple services. Every service use a RestTemplate bean. In this RestTemplate bean, I want to get the UUID.

```
@Component
public class ZenithRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {   
    @Autowired
    private UUID uuid;

    public void buildRestTemplate() {
        List restTemplateInterceptors = new ArrayList();
        restTemplateInterceptors.add(new HeaderHttpRequestInterceptor("UUID", uuid.toString()));
        this.setInterceptors(restTemplateInterceptors);
    }
}
```

When I try to inject the UUID here, I have an error :

> Error creating bean with name 'zenithRestTemplate': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.UUID com.geodis.rt.zenith.framework.webui.service.ZenithRestTemplate.uuid; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestUUID': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

What can I do to access my UUID bean inside the RestTemplate bean ?

My project use Spring-MVC, Spring-boot with java configuration.

I already tried to add a RequestContextListener but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
@Bean public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you need to mark your `UUID` request scoped bean like:

```
@Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Where controller is `singleton` scoped bean you are injecting `request` scoped bean in it. As singleton beans are injected only once per their lifetime you need to provide scoped beans as proxies which takes care of that.

Another option is to instead use the `org.springframework.web.context.annotation.RequestScope` annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public @interface RequestScope {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Scope.class)
    ScopedProxyMode proxyMode() default ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS;

}
```

`@RequestScope` is a meta-annotation on `@Scope` that 1) sets the `scope` to `"request"` and 2) sets the `proxyMode` to `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` so you don't have to do it every time you want to define a request-scoped bean.

**Edit:**

Note that you may need to add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on your main configuration class.

Comment: I just realized that it probably solves only part of the problem. Is the template thing running still from the same thread?

Comment: I try some modification and I had another error that says that I can't subclass a final class (UUID class is final).
I change my bean UUID bean to use a custom class with an UUID attribute and now it works.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation. I think that was my problem.

Comment: With Spring Boot, we don't need `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625149/spring-aop-works-without-enableaspectjautoproxy