# How to inject request scoped bean?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, requestscope

I want to inject my request scoped bean to my other bean.

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public class UiCtx {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ServletWebRequest req;

    // [...]
}
```

I try to inject this bean to a `JPage` bean:

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Jpage extends AbstractUiComponent {
   // [...]
}

public abstract class AbstractUiComponent  {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private UiCtx ctx;
    // [...]
}
```

In the controller I have tried:

```java
@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/jpage")
    void jpage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @Autowired @Qualifier("jpage") AbstractUiComponent jpage) throws IOException {
        WritePage.writeWebPage(request, response, jpage);
       }
    }
}
```

I got:

> Failed to instantiate [pl.mirage.components.AbstractUiComponent]:
> Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is
> java.lang.InstantiationException

Another attempt. It doesn't work because `@RestController` is a singleton - you can't inject request scope into singleton scope:

```java
@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jpage")
    AbstractUiComponent jpage;

    @RequestMapping("/jpage")
    void jpage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        WritePage.writeWebPage(request, response, jpage);
    }
}
```

I got:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'jpage'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'jpage': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'ctx'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'uiCtx': Scope 'request' is not active for the
> current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you
> intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
> you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
> or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
> you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
> message, your code is probably running outside of
> DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
> RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
> request.

It is possible to fix this by annotating `UICtx` or `JPage` as `@Scope(value = "[..]", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`.

It only works when `JPage` is injected as a controller field. It doesn't work when `JPage` is injected as a method parameter.

How do I suppose to inject a request scoped bean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject request scoped bean into another bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090750/inject-request-scoped-bean-into-another-bean)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the advice (which I emphasized in bold) given in error-message:

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uiCtx': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; **consider defining a scoped proxy** for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;

You need the `proxyMode` to boot the app with `UICtx` dependency injected, e.g. define

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UiCtx {
   // omitted class body
}
```

or shorthand [`@RequestScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html). See [Baeldung Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#1-request-scope) or duplicate linked in [Tom's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444465/how-to-inject-request-scoped-bean#comment73953191_43444465):

[Inject request scoped bean into another bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090750/inject-request-scoped-bean-into-another-bean)