# Why my @Aspect is not recognized by my SpringBoot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect, spring-aspects

I want to test the AOP with spring boot, hence I imported this dependency in my

> pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then i created two classes, one for configuration and an other responsible for weaving aspect.

> AspectConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.douineau.aspect")
public class AspectConfig {

}
```

And the other class, which does nothing special except testing if it's working well :

> ControllerAspect.class

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ControllerAspect {
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.douineau.aspect.ControllerAspect.testAop(..))")
    public void callingRequest() {
        System.out.println("Pointcut method done");
    }
    
    @Before("callingRequest()")
    public void beforeAdvice( ) {
        System.out.println("Before advice");
    }

    public void testAop() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

When i'm calling the method `c.testAop()`, it is supposed to enter in the method `callingRequest()` with the parameterized `@Pointcut("execution(* com.douineau.aspect.ControllerAspect.testAop(..))")` annotation.

But it don't...

An other thing to really understand, does it would be more pertinent to place the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation directly after the `@SpringBootApplication` of the main SpringBoot launcher ?

Thank you for your help.

Joss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Spring framework reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-at-aspectj):

> Advising aspects with other aspects? In Spring AOP, aspects themselves
> cannot be the targets of advice from other aspects. The @Aspect
> annotation on a class marks it as an aspect and, hence, excludes it
> from auto-proxying.

Here the pointcut expression is targeting an Aspect , which is not possible in Spring AOP.

For a Spring Boot application , one need not explicitly declare `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. Please read through this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48625149/4214241)

As long as the [recommeded structuring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code) is followed , your aspects should be picked without explicitly specifying a `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Thank you, if I did understand well, I have to call the method testAop from another class, and I can get rid of my EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation which is useless because it's already managed by the SpringBootApplication annotation ?

Comment: Not exactly 1. You can advice a Spring bean using Spring AOP , which means , the `testAop()` method should be in a bean ( which is not an aspect ) and the point cut designator should be targeting that method. 2. Yes , `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is redundant as it is managed by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: Please update the question with your new code