# Not able to run @Advice catch Exception block

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

This is my Aop Aspect that I have created to run after my main app throws an error.

```java
package com.demo.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAroundAspect {

  @Around("execution(* com.demo.aop.*.getFortune(..))")
  public Object aroundAdviceDemo(ProceedingJoinPoint thePJP) throws Throwable
  {
    System.out.println("run this before the fortune method");

    Object result = null;
    try {
      result = thePJP.proceed();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {   //this should run but is not running
      System.out.println("Catching the " + exc.getMessage());
    }


    System.out.println("Run this after the fortune service");

    return result;
  }
}
```

This is my trafficFortuneservuce class which has a method that is throwing an error and I am trying to catch that error using my @Around advice.

```java
package com.demo.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class TrafficFortuneService {

  public String getFortune(boolean tripwire)
  {
    if(tripwire)
    {    //this is running but it should go to the advice catch block
      throw new RuntimeException("Inside run time exception in the fortune service");
    }

    return "Today is your lucky day";
  }
}
```

This is my main method class where I am running my app.

```java
package com.demo.aop.app;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.demo.aop.Account;
import com.demo.aop.AccountDAO;
import com.demo.aop.AppConfig;
import com.demo.aop.MemberDAO;
import com.demo.aop.TrafficFortuneService;

public class AroundDemoApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Getting context object
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    TrafficFortuneService theService = context.getBean("trafficFortuneService", TrafficFortuneService.class);
    boolean tripwire = true;
    String temp =   theService.getFortune(tripwire);

    System.out.println(temp);

    context.close();
  }
}
```

Here is the output, which is printing the message that I have declared in the `trafficfortuneservice` class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Inside run time exception in the fortune service
    at com.demo.aop.TrafficFortuneService.getFortune(TrafficFortuneService.java:15)
    at com.demo.aop.app.AroundDemoApp.main(AroundDemoApp.java:20)
```

Comment: the problem is not the exception not being catched, but `aroundAdviceDemo` not even being called at all (as it should show the first system.out you declared)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be nice to show some respect towards the people who are trying to help you by replying to them. Your feedback would help us to finally resolve your issue, if for some reason none of the answers posted so far help you answer your question. If however one of them solves your problem, please be encouraged to mark it as accepted by clicking the grey check mark, making it green. 

Answer (score 1):

Add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to your spring config class (add to `MyAroundAspect.java` is OK).

Spring Boot will automatically open this function with `@SpringBootApplication` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626789/9304616), so in normal spring boot application, it's not mandatory to mark this annotation manually. But in your case, you are starting the application manually, so it just not works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make your normal application class an `@Aspect`. Firstly, it does not make any sense. Secondly, Spring AOP aspects cannot advise each other, so you are effectively stopping yourself from achieving your goal, shooting yourself in the foot.

---

**Update:** I was talking about this:

```java
//@Aspect <-- You got to get rid of this, the serice is not an aspect!
@Component
public class TrafficFortuneService {
  // (...)
}
```